# Refactoring conditional statements among different classes

Tags: java, design-patterns

I wonder there is any method of refactoring nested condition.  It's just the same content with different contents and different classes which looks bad.  I really want to reform this code which looks bad.

My sample code consists of the same conditions with different classes and contents.

```
public class AService extends BaseService {
    public Map action(AModel aModel throws Exception{
        Map model = new HashMap();

        try {
            if(aModel.getTrStatus().equals(TrStatus.CREATE))
            {
                aDao.add(acrAccessAreaModel);
                aModel.setTrStatus(Constants.TrStatus.UPDATE.toString());

                int attrNo = 0;
                if(aModel.getImgPath()!=null && aModel.getImgPath().getSize()>0)
                    attrNo = fileService.fileWrite(Constants.ServiceId.ACR_AREA, aModel.getAccssAreaId().toString(), aModel.getImgPath());

                if(attrNo != 0)
                {
                    aModel.setAttrNo(attrNo);
                    aDao.modify(acrAccessAreaModel);
                }

                model.put("accAreaInfo", acrAccessAreaModel);
            }
            else if(aModel.getTrStatus().equals(TrStatus.UPDATE))
            {    

                if(aModel.getImgPath()!=null && aModel.getImgPath().getSize()>0)
                {
                    if(aModel.getAttrNo() != null)
                    {
                        FileModel fileModel = new FileModel();                    
                        fileModel.setFileSeq(aModel.getAccssAreaId().toString());
                        fileModel.setAttrNo(aModel.getAttrNo());
                        fileService.remove(fileModel);
                    }

                    int attrNo = 0;
                    attrNo = fileService.fileWrite(Constants.ServiceId.ACR_COLOR, aModel.getAccssAreaId().toString(), aModel.getImgPath());

                    if(attrNo != 0)
                        aModel.setAttrNo(attrNo);
                }

                aDao.modify(acrAccessAreaModel);

            }
            else if(aModel.getTrStatus().equals(TrStatus.DELETE))
            {
                for (Map<String,String> accInfo : aModel.getAccssAreaList()) {
                    if(accInfo.get("attrNo") != null && !accInfo.get("attrNo").equals(""))
                    {
                        FileModel fileModel = new FileModel();
                        fileModel.setFileSeq(accInfo.get("accssAreaId").toString());
                        fileModel.setAttrNo(Integer.parseInt(accInfo.get("attrNo")));
                        fileService.remove(fileModel);
                    }

                    aDao.remove(accInfo);
                    aDao.removeAccArea(accInfo);
                    aDao.removeGate(accInfo);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

        return model;
    }

     }



public class BService extends BaseService {

    public Map action(BModel bModel) throws Exception{  

        Map model = new HashMap();
            try{
                if(bModel.getTrStatus().equals(TrStatus.CREATE)){

                    model.put("save",bDao.add(acrAccCtrlStdmModel));

                } else if(bModel.getTrStatus().equals(TrStatus.UPDATE)){

                    model.put("save",bDao.up(acrAccCtrlStdmModel));

                } else if (bModel.getTrStatus().equals(TrStatus.DELETE)){

                    for(Map<String, String> stdmId : bModel.getAcrDelList()){
                        bDao.del(stdmId);
                    }                            
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Exception(e);
            }
            return model;
        }
    }


public class CService extends BaseService {
    public Map aciton(CModel cModel) throws Exception{
        Map model = new HashMap();
        List<Map<String,String>> acrAreaList = null;
        String gateId = "";
        try{
            if(cModel.getTrStatus().equals(TrStatus.CREATE)){

                cDao.saveGate(cModel);
                cModel.setGateId(cModel.getGateId());
                gateId = acrAccCtrlcModel.getGateId().toString();
                acrAreaList = cModel.getAcrAreaList();

                for (Map<String,String> acrArea : acrAreaList) {    
                    acrArea.put("gateId",         gateId);
                    acrArea.put("crerId",         cModel.getCrerId());
                    acrArea.put("updrId",         cModel.getUpdrId());
                    cDao.save(acrArea);
                }            
                model.put("save",acrAccCtrlGateModel);
            }else if (cModel.getTrStatus().equals(TrStatus.DELETE)){

                for(Map<String, String> acrDelList : acrAccCtrlGateModel.getAcrDelList()){
                    cDao.delGate(acrDelList);
                    cDao.del(acrDelList);
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know your submited code can't compile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Time to review, while I think your second line just have a typ fault I will not consider that.

### Implement abstract method with use of generics.

All your Service extends `BaseService`.
I see the method `public Map action(AModel aModel) throws Exception{` for AService.
I see the method `public Map action(BModel bModel) throws Exception{` for BService.
I see the method `public Map aciton(CModel cModel) throws Exception{` for CService.(*I asume typo?*)

You can put this abstract method to the BaseService if you use generics.

So it could look like this for BaseService :

```
public abstract class BaseService<T> {

    public abstract Map action(T model);

}
```

And for the AService this should be the result :

```
public class AService extends BaseService<AModel> {

    @Override
    public Map action(AModel model) {

    }
}
```

### if - else if - else if ...

When you see this, it's time to consider switch statements.
I hope the `TrStatus` is an enum, so you can refactor this to a switch.
If it is a String, you need java 7 or higher to do switch on Strings.

Code can be as followed :

```
switch (cModel.getTrStatus()) {
    case TrStatus.CREATE:  
        createTrgStatusAction(cmodel);
        break;
    case TrStatus.DELETE:  
        deleteTrgStatusAction();
        break;
     default :  
        // you can put code here what to do if no one of these cases is correct.
        break;
}
```

### Naming of methods, variables and classes

Well, it's sample code and I hope it's because of that, but some of your naming is realy awfull.
`AService`, `BService` and `CService` shall never speak to me that I know what kind of service it is.
`BaseService` on the other hand is well chosen.
The same as for names of the DAO's => cDao ...

### Use constants for (recurring) "magic" String's.

```
model.put("save",bDao.add(acrAccCtrlStdmModel));
```

The "save" String comes twice in your class.
You could create a constant for that.

```
private static final String SAVE = "save";
```

So your code should become :

```
model.put(SAVE,bDao.add(acrAccCtrlStdmModel));
```

### Implement more methods to reduce method complexity

Like I already showed you with the switch case, make methods what do less things.
This reduce the complexity of your method.
Readability of the code comes higher and troubleshooting goes easier.

```
private void createTrgStatusAction(CModel cmodel) {
    cDao.saveGate(cModel);
    cModel.setGateId(cModel.getGateId());
    gateId = acrAccCtrlcModel.getGateId().toString();
    acrAreaList = cModel.getAcrAreaList();

    for (Map<String,String> acrArea : acrAreaList) {    
        acrArea.put("gateId", gateId);
        acrArea.put("crerId", cModel.getCrerId());
        acrArea.put("updrId", cModel.getUpdrId());
        cDao.save(acrArea);
    }            
    model.put("save",acrAccCtrlGateModel);
}
```

As you can see this is already a lit clearder of what it does.
You put yourself a white space just before the for loop.
You seperate 2 different actions there so refactor this method further so it will look somthing like this in the end :

```
private void createTrgStatusAction(CModel cmodel) {
    updateModel(cmodel);
    saveTheForLoop(cmodel); // Please name this better.         
    model.put("save",acrAccCtrlGateModel);
}
```

### Catch en rethrow error

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new Exception(e);
}
```

This is just one bad piece.
You catch an exception, doesn't do a thing with it and creates a new exception to be trown.
**First of all**, try to catch the detailed exception if possible.
**Secondly**, If you need to throw the exception back you could use :

```
throw e;
```

**Third**, in this case the whole try catch you can remove cause you trows through the method the exception to higher place.

### Use braces for if

```
if(attrNo != 0)
    aModel.setAttrNo(attrNo);
```

The intendation is correct but **always** use braces for if's.
A lot of mistakes with if's comes from this.
Example  :

```
int number;
if (someCondition)
    if (otherCondition)
        number = 5;
else number = 3;
```

The else counts on what if?
Mine intendation clearly says the first if, will the compiler see that also like this?
If I change mine intendation, the compiler shall still give the same result, but I clearly mean something else at that point.
Putting braces is a small effort to do, you lose a lot more time searching a fault like that.

Comment: +1 for throwing a new exception in the catch being a bad idea. Not sure about Java, but in C# doing this eliminates the stack trace. If Java exceptions can have *inner exceptions*, then throwing a new exception should keep the initial exception as the *inner exception*. And throwing `Exception` is always a bad call, one should throw *meaningful* exception types. Nice answer!